# How do I use VScode's debugger when I want to run specific command through my terminal?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am currently working on some python homework using VScode. However, I'm not sure how to use debugger for VScode for specific command that I have to manually input through my git bash terminal.

Whenever I test my code, I have to either manually type in some command such as:

```
python xxx.py -l some_file -p some_file -a fn=some_function
```

or write above code on text file (say, foo.txt) and run

```
bash foo.txt
```

on my Git Bash terminal to test my result. However, putting breakpoint on certain part of code doesn't not stop as well as modifying .json file would not let me debug the code.

I've tried using "args", "programs", etc and still have no luck. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`args` in your `launch.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_args):

```
"args": ["-l", "some_file", "-p", "some_file", "-a", "fn=some_function"]
```

Remember that anything that is meant to have a space separating it must be it's own string in the array.